# Is there a way to get DS games to use the full top screen on a 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I noticed that when I play DS games on my 3DS, the games don't fill the entirety of the top screen on the 3DS - there are black bars on either side of the image.

Is there a way to get the game to fill the entire screen? Or is that just going to make things look terrible?

Comment: FWIW someone (Sono on gbatemp) started investigating the possibility quite recently and actually achieved [some progress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Qg9giftkhc). This is however still in development and will require a hacked 3DS to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There appears to be two modes for playing DS games on the 3DS.  If you hold Select+Start while the DS game is loading, it will display in it's "[Native Resolution](http://www.kotaku.com.au/2011/03/how-the-3ds-alters-ds-games-and-what-you-should-do-about-it/)" on the 3DS screens.

Unfortunately, this is going to make the black bars bigger and not smaller.  As far as I can tell, this is the only other display mode that the 3DS supports when playing DS games.

It has to do with the different resolutions/aspect ratios of the DS and the 3DS.  Similar things happened when playing GB games on the GBA.

Comment: If they allowed you to "fix" this it would be stretching the image. Any "proper fix" would involve a firmware update allowing "ds mode" to have the full screen, changing the rendering code in the game to match. The latter is a very invasive operation, and would have to be done on a "custom" basis for every game. For some, it's a good question what they would be doing with that extra screen space to begin with, since the layout was designed with the smaller screen in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not that I know of. The only way for you to play the DS games is with the format it gives you.